# How does my car buttons communicate with the car dashboard?

Tags: electrical, car, mmi

I have an Audi A6 3,2 FSI 2004 model. Needless to say the multi media system isn't what it could be. I work as a computer programmer so naturally it peaked my interest to know how the multi media system works. I have a hard time finding information about this, perhaps I don't ask the right questions because of my very limited understanding of hardware and cars in general.

If you look at this picture for reference:

[image]

You'll see that there's several components that interact with the dashboard. There's the volume button, the menu button (the big circle in the middle), different buttons to active different sections in the dashboard (Radio, CD, Car, etc).

If you look at the steering wheel there's also two buttons and volume and radio controls.

I want to understand how these different components send messages to the dashboard, what wires, how the communication works, and how I could decode those messages. With this information I'd like to make my own dashboard with e.g a raspberry pi and a touch screen.

Any information steering me in the right direction is very helpful, or any resources such as documentation, books, et cetera.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm pretty sure the steering wheel controls are done through RF functions ... at least that seems to be the common way to do it. This makes it so there's no real wires from these buttons through the steering wheel and out to the head unit. Makes life a lot easier. As far as dash controls, I'd suspect these are going to be hard wired. Easiest way to tell is to take the dash apart.

Comment: It [piqued](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pique) your interest

Comment: Proprietary info isn't revealed in detailed schematics but your source of info would be from factory service manuals if Audi has them via hard copy, Alldata or Mitchell (the latter two are online subscription services). General signal flow from service manuals and description of signal protocols, enough to whet your appetite and maybe allow experimentation with custom interfaces. Since aftermarket scantools acquire info to create clones of factory scantools, I presume there's enough info for anyone with skills to experiment.